# Given $\ z= \frac{f(x-y)}{y}$ show that $\ z + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The problem:

Given $\ z= \frac{f(x-y)}{y}$ show that $\ z + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 0$

I'm having problems at computing the partial derivatives of z, do I have to apply a change of variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}=\frac{f'(x-y)}{y}$$
$$\frac{\delta z}{\delta y}=\frac{-(f'(x-y)\times y +f(x-y))}{y^2}$$

Therefore $$z+y.\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}+y\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}=z-\frac{f(x-y)}{y}=0$$

Basically, in $\frac{\delta z}{\delta y}$, diffrenciate $z$ taking $y$ as the variable and $x$ constant while in  $\frac{\delta z}{\delta x}$ diffrenciate taking $x$ as the variable and $y$ as constant